# Use index for ORDER BY in "SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE column IN (...) ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to make the following query use an index and not use filesort:

```
SELECT c1 FROM table WHERE c2 IN (val_1, val_2, ..., val_n) ORDER BY c3
```

I guess chances are bad so if it is not possible is there any way to make the following problem use indexes (or be fast):

The table contains comments from users:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(180) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL)

  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I want to output the comments of specific users (for example the ones who user_x is following) ordered by timestamp (compare query above).

The only way I can imagine making this query fast is to insert a new variable that is set to 1 for the last let's say 15 entries of a single user. So the first query would just get a maximum of 15 rows per user so the maximum amount of rows mysql has to order is 15*n, where n is the amount of users the comments are selected from.

**Edit:** This is what EXPLAIN outputs:

```
id  select_type table    type   possible_keys                   key                             key_len   ref   rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      comments range  idx_comments_user_id_timestamp  idx_comments_user_id_timestamp  4         NULL  1113    Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found an example for the SELECT IN statement. (But the farther I understand the logic behind the query the more I doubt that using an index is possible).

Comment: Do you have a lot of vals in the in statement - if so it may be worth pushing them into another table (indexed) and joining rather than using an in statement.

Comment: The amount of vals is defined by the maximum number of users a user can follow (maybe capped at 100). I don't think it is a good idea to save all the comments for each individual users followed users, this is a huge amount of redundant data.

Comment: I guess I will just limit the output of the filter condition so a filesort does not have to sort too many entries. In user experience this is not noticable as long as the user doesn't have a very small amount of followed users and wants to see a lot of (older) entries of them.

Comment: So in non-code language an example would be: Get the last 15 comments of each user I am following (I cannot follow more than 50 users) and put them together. Use filesort on this and ouput it ordered by the timestamp. On 15 comments per user and a maximum of 50 followed user this would be 750 rows. I think this is ok.

Comment: Where's the EXPLAIN?

Comment: @Strawberry I added the EXPLAIN output in the op.